# Zend Framwork 2: correct way to share view between controllers

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

Which is the most correct way in zf2 to share view between a controller that is extended from another controller. Let say have to controller A and B. A extends B:

```
class AController extends BController{

}

class BController{
 public action shareAction(){
 }
}
```

**1 way**, put in module config the view path of action share pointing to B share view;

```
'template_map' => array(
    'a/index/index'   => __DIR__ . '/../view/a/index.phtml',
    'a/share/index'     => __DIR__ . '../../../../view/b/share/share.phtml',//SCALE TO REACH B VIEW
```

**2 way**, put in module config the view path of action share pointing to local view path

```
'template_map' => array(
    'a/index/index'   => __DIR__ . '/../view/a/index.phtml',
    'a/share/index'     => __DIR__ . '../view/a/share/share.phtml',
```

and in share.phtml of a put:

```
echo $this->partial('b/share/index')
```

OR if there is another best way, which?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the template on an action by action basis too:

```
public function testAction()
{
    // If you wanted to change the actual base layout template:
    //$this->layout()->setTemplate('my/layout/base-layout.phtml');

    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setTemplate('my/template/here');

    return $viewModel;
}
```

The method you chose would depend how/why you want to do this, and if there's a pattern to the override or weather it's more of an adhoc basis. Above if fine if you are just planning to change the template in an adhoc manner

Comment: I know this way, but let say this is generic, it just for changing template on the fly. I was just asking the best way to share view between to classes that are extended.